# UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay open new UIViewController as button plays audiofile

Tags: iphone

In my application have UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay on the mainwindow and i want to implement something like this as audiofile starts playing it opens pages one by one synchronized with the audiofile.

Anyone have any ideas how to implement it.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

My best suggestion would be the following:

1. Create an NSMutableArray containing NSIntegers representing the time-marks where you want the pages to change.
2. Set a timer to start running when the audio file starts. Have it increment an NSInteger every second.
3. In the timer's selector method, test the incremented number against the array and see if it's there.
4. If there, go to the next page.